# linq expression (entity) with sum in subselect

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity

I am new to Entity, and have a question regarding a LINQ statement.

Below appears my code, it appears with exception to "TotalFoults" field. He always gives 0.

Could anyone help me because all the results in the "TotalFoults" column have a value above zero.

Thank you very much.

```
var result = (from sr in db.StudentsResult
             join F in db.Fouls on sr.Enrollment equals F.Enrollment into F_join
             from F in F_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join S in db.Students on sr.Enrollment equals S.Enrollment into A_join
             from A in A_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where
               F.Day != null
             group new { sr, s } by new
             {
              sr.Enrollment ,
              sr.Name,
              sr.Number,
              sr.Classes,
              s.Discount
             } into g
             orderby
             g.Key.Classes,
             g.Key.Number,
             g.Key.Name
              select new frequencyMod()
               {
              Enrollment = g.Key.Enrollment ,
              StudentName = g.Key.Name,
              StudentFile= g.Key.Number,
              Classes = g.Key.Classes,
              TotalFoults = (from m0 in db.Foults
              where
              m0.Enrollment == g.Key.Enrollment 
              group m0 by new
              {
              m0.Enrollment 
                  } into a
                   select new
                   {
                   Total = a.Sum(p => p.Foults)
                   }).FirstOrDefault().Total
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Your code isn't that beautiful. Looks like you're trying to translate SQL to a LINQ query in a ugly way. Maybe you could give som information about the database and what result you want and we can help you that way instead of trying to understand everything that's going on in your code.